# Unable to handle exception

Tags: http-error

I am using clearbit module to get the company information from the domain name. I tried to handle HTTPException, but somehow it is not recognized and throwing one more Exception NameError.

```py
import clearbit 
def abc(i): 
try: 
  company = clearbit.Company.find(domain=i,stream=True) 
  if company['name'] is None: 
           return "No customer" 
  else: return company['name'] 
except HTTPError as e: 
   s="No customer" 
    return s 
abc('244treqda.com')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-43005b4345c0> in abc(i)
      3     try:
----> 4         company = clearbit.Company.find(domain=i,stream=True)
      5         if company['name'] is None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clearbit\enrichment\company.py in find(cls, **options)
     15 
---> 16         return cls.get(url, **options)
     17 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clearbit\resource.py in get(cls, url, **values)
     54         else:
---> 55             response.raise_for_status()
     56 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    939         if http_error_msg:
--> 940             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    941 

HTTPError: 422 Client Error: Unprocessable Entity for url: https://company-stream.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=244treqda.com

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-153-8c883a3f90d2> in <module>
----> 1 abc('244treqda.com')

<ipython-input-152-43005b4345c0> in abc(i)
      7         else:
      8             return company['name']
----> 9     except HTTPError as e:
     10         s="No customer"
     11         return s

NameError: name 'HTTPError' is not defined

In [119]:



try:
   clearbit.Company.find(domain=i,stream=True)
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
   if err.code == 422:
       return "No customer"
```

Expected output "No customer" but getting HTTPError and Attributeerror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look a bit further in the stack trace you see

`NameError: name 'HTTPError' is not defined`

The `HTTPError` is not a built in python exception - you'll need to import this from an appropriate module in order to catch that type of exception.

At the top of your python module add `from urllib.error import HTTPError` and it should work.

Alternatively find the exact `HTTPError` being thrown from `clearbit` and import that if the first option doesn't work.